# How to read url of my image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set src to dynamically appended image in my script, the user firstly browse his image and enter his name in text field then clicks on add button then dynamically appended a table row.

In that I want to show the image. Is there any mistake in my script?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addbtn').click(function() {
    var val = $.trim($('#txt-val').val());
    var some = $('#imagefile').val();
    if (val != '') {
      //$('#imagepath').attr('src','+some+');

      $("imagefile").change(function() {
        readURL('#imagefile');
      });


      $('#newval').append('<option>' + val + '</option>');
      $('#list-tbl').append('<tr height=\"50\">' + '<td>' + val + '<img id=\"imagepath\" src="#" style="width:50px; height:50px;"/>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + val + '</td>' + '</tr>');

    }
    $('#txt-val').val('');

  });

  function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#imagepath')
          .attr('src', e.target.result)
          .width(150)
          .height(200);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.dynamictbl {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="imagefile" onchange="readURL(this);" />
<input type="text" style="width:150px;" id="txt-val" />
<button id="addbtn">Add</button>
<select id="newval" style="width:150px;"></select>
<div style="width:100%; height:300px; margin-top:5px; overflow:auto;">
  <table id="list-tbl" class="dynamictbl">
    <tr height="50">
      <th width="50%">Index Of Entry<span id="img"></span>
      </th>
      <th width="50%">User Name</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I see an error: change  $("imagefile").change(function(){ to $("#imagefile").change(function(){  hope this help you

Comment: **Just a tip:** Use [URL.createObjectURL(blob)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) instead

Answer (score 0):

take the readURL() function outside of the jquery ready function

Comment: Its Not Working

Answer (score 0):

readURL function is not accessible from the click event, so make it should be moved to been accessible.
Also readURL() should be called after adding elements to DOM and not on "onChange" event.

```
window.readURL = function(id) {
    var input = $('#imagefile')[0];
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {

    $('#'+id)
      .attr('src', e.target.result)
      .width(150)
      .height(200);
  };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
};

 $(document).ready(function() {
  var rows = 0;
   $('#addbtn').click(function() {
  var val = $.trim($('#txt-val').val());
  var some = $('#imagefile').val();
  if (val != '') {

    var id = 'imagepath' + (++rows);

    $('#newval').append('<option>' + val + '</option>');
    $('#list-tbl').append('<tr height=\"50\">' + '<td>' + val + '<img id=\"' + id + '\" src="#" style="width:50px; height:50px;"/>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + val + '</td>' + '</tr>');
    readURL(id);

  }
    $('#txt-val').val('');
   });

 });
```

Working sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/4gyq1kvb/14/